# Winter Bash profile hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

It seems that the profile in the [Winter Bash site](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com) doesn't have a hat:

[image: Image 1]

Shouldn't it join in the celebration too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works for me:

[image: screen shot]

The hats take a little longer to load than the rest of the site; maybe you didn't wait long enough?

Comment: Thanks, may be caused by cacheing too. I just wore a hat :)

Comment: Yeah, you do have to actually wear one. :-) . And wait for that to work its way through the system.

Comment: Yup, I meant I wore a hat and promptly visited the Winter Bash page. Maybe it takes a while longer before the hat gets "registered" throughout SE ;-)